# If $ \:\phi(n)\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} -\phi(n+1)>v$ then $\sum a_n$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n >0 $, and $\phi:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$

If $\exists N$ such that $\forall n > N$ we have:

$$ \:\phi(n)\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} -\phi(n+1)>v$$

with $v \in \mathbb{R}^{*}_{+}$, then $\sum a_n$ converges.

All I managed to do is to play with the inequality giving me this:

$$\frac{\phi (n)}{v+\phi (n+1)} \geq \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} $$

This I should maybe prove that the right side is inferior to one, but no idea how to do that.

Comment: You are close to applying the ratio test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test, the only problem is, what is $\phi(n)$? Euler's totient function?

Comment: @rtybase That's issue, it's just an unknown function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting $c_n=\phi(n)$ for each $n$ to simplify the notation,

we have that 
 $ \;\;a_nc_n-a_{n+1}c_{n+1}>v a_{n+1}$ for $n>N$.

Then $\displaystyle \sum_{n=N+1}^{N+k}\left(a_nc_n-a_{n+1}c_{n+1}\right)\;>\sum_{n=N+1}^{N+k}v a_{n+1}\;$ for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$,

so $\hspace{.12 in}\displaystyle a_{N+1}c_{N+1}-a_{N+k+1}c_{N+k+1}\;>v\sum_{n=N+1}^{N+k}a_{n+1}$.

Thus $\hspace{.12 in}\displaystyle \sum_{n=N+1}^{N+k}a_{n+1}\;<\frac{a_{N+1}c_{N+1}}{v}\;$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N},\;\;$ so $\displaystyle\sum_{n>N} a_n$ converges.

Comment: The insight here is that rearranging the given inequality one can get a bounding telescoping series.